# Image cannot be loaded. Available decoders

Tags: c#, imagesharp

Trying to load a image with ImageSharp, I get this:
Image cannot be loaded. Available decoders:

- BMP : BmpDecoder
- GIF : GifDecoder
- PBM : PbmDecoder
- JPEG : JpegDecoder
- PNG : PngDecoder
- TGA : TgaDecoder
- Webp : WebpDecoder
- TIFF : TiffDecoder

I try to load in 2 ways. The first is with this method, this received a byte array from other method where I load with a File System.

```
private byte[] FileToSizedImageSource1(String file, int width, int height)
    {
        byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
        return this.FileToSizedImageSource2(data, width, height);
    }

private byte[] FileToSizedImageSource2(byte[] data, int x, int y)
    {
        byte[] result = null;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            var raw = Image.Load(memoryStream);
            var clone = raw.Clone(context => context
                        .Resize(new ResizeOptions
                        {
                            Mode = ResizeMode.Max,
                            Size = new Size(x, y)
                        }));
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Position = 0;
                clone.Save(ms, new PngEncoder { CompressionLevel = PngCompressionLevel.DefaultCompression });
                byte[] img_buffer = ms.ToArray();
                result = Compress(img_buffer);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And the other way is loading with the own ImageSharp

```
private byte[] FileToSizedImageSource2(string path, int x, int y)
    {
        byte[] result = null;
        using (var raw = Image.Load(path))
        {
            var clone = raw.Clone(context => context
                        .Resize(new ResizeOptions
                        {
                            Mode = ResizeMode.Max,
                            Size = new Size(x, y)
                        }));
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Position = 0;
                clone.Save(ms, new PngEncoder { CompressionLevel = PngCompressionLevel.DefaultCompression });
                byte[] img_buffer = ms.ToArray();
                result = Compress(img_buffer);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What kind of image is it? Where did it come from?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I edited the post, I tried to load a jpg and png image, in this example is png image.

Comment: Are you 100% sure, the file is ok? Can you display/open it in other applications/viewers?

Comment: @Fildor absolutely

Comment: what line are you failing at exactly? your not trying to open the `result` byte array as an image are you and thats the part thats failing .... without the source image thats failing no one will really be able to debug this. and if your failing at on of the visible `Image.Load(...)` calls then the rest of the code is not helpfull to your issue and probably shouldn't be included... you want your test/error code to be as minimal as possible.

Comment: @tocsoft i think the line that is failing is the clone.Save(....), commenting that ```using``` block, i dont have error.

Comment: Can you please visit the discussions channel here bringing the image in question?

https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/discussions/categories/q-a